# Format for storing json in Amazon DynamoDB

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I've got JSON file that looks like this

```
{
  "alliance":{
    "name_part_1":[
      "Ab",
      "Aen",
      "Zancl"
    ],
    "name_part_2":[
      "aca",
      "acia",
      "ythrae",
      "ytos"
    ],
    "name_part_3":[
      "Alliance",
      "Bond"
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to store it in `dynamoDB`. 
The thing is that I want a generator that would take random elements from fields like `name_part_1`, `name_part_2` and others (number of `name_parts_x` is unlimited and overalls number of items in each parts might be several hundreds) and join them to create a complete word. Like

```
name_part_1[1] + name_part_2[10] + name_part[3]
```

My question is that what format I should use to do that effectively? Or NoSQL shouldn't be used for that? Should I refactor JSON for something like

```
{
    "name": "alliance",
    "parts": [ "name_part_1", "name_part_2", "name_part_3" ],
    "values": [
        { "name_part_1" : [ "Ab ... ] }, { "name_part_2": [ "aca" ... ] }  
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect use case for DynamoDB.

You can structure like this,

```
NameParts (Table)
    namepart (partition key)
    range (hash key)
```

> namepart: name_part_1  range: 0  value: "Ab"

This way each name_part will have its own range and scalable. You can extend it to thousands or even millions.

You can do a batch getitem from the sdk of your choice and join those values.

**REST API reference:**
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchGetItem.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: but what if another `name` (armor instead of alliance) has `name_part_1` then how should it be handled?

Answer (score 0):

You can just put the whole document as it is in DynamoDB and then use [document path](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.Attributes.html) to access the elements you want.

> Document Paths
>
> In an expression, you use a document path to tell DynamoDB where to
>   find an attribute. For a top-level attribute, the document path is
>   simply the attribute name. For a nested attribute, you construct the
>   document path using dereference operators.
>
> The following are some examples of document paths. (Refer to the item
>   shown in Specifying Item Attributes.)
>
> A top-level scalar attribute: ProductDescription A top-level list
>   attribute. (This will return the entire list, not just some of the
>   elements.) RelatedItems The third element from the RelatedItems list.
>   (Remember that list elements are zero-based.) RelatedItems[2] The
>   front-view picture of the product. Pictures.FrontView All of the
>   five-star reviews. ProductReviews.FiveStar The first of the five-star
>   reviews. ProductReviews.FiveStar[0] Note The maximum depth for a
>   document path is 32. Therefore, the number of dereferences operators
>   in a path cannot exceed this limit.

Note that each document requires a unique Partition Key.